# Full Stack: Http failure response for url: 0 Unknown Error

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am trying to deploy my full stack application built using MySQL, Express, Angular and Node on Plesk Obsidian. However, I am facing an issue during the deployment. When my client side sends a request to the server then, I get the following error:

"Http failure response for https://example.com:3000/api/mytargetapi: 0 Unknown Error"

"GET ... net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Everything was working smoothly until I deployed it on Plesk.

Here's my code of the request on the client side:

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('id', this.searchInDirectory);
  this.http.get('https://example.com:3000/api/mytargetapi', {params})
  .subscribe(response => 
  {
    this.itemDisplay = response;
  }
```

server side:

```
var app = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use(routes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const host = 'localhost';
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
});

router.get('/api/mytargetapi', (req, res) => {
  
     stuff here...

}
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? I have searched the same question on stack overflow and followed each and every individual's solution but nothing seems to be working for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're organizing your project structure for the back-end API, but you should test the API via POSTMAN before integration with your front-end client

```
 var app = express();
  
    
    app.disable('x-powered-by');
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    app.use(cors());
    app.get('/api/mytargetapi', (req, res) => {
     
         stuff here...
    }
   
    app.use(routes);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const host = 'localhost';
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    
    server.listen(port, host, () => {
      console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
    });
```